# how to get exception cause and message in java form multiple classes

Tags: java, exception

I have developed an Servlet  , the  processReq() calls a method of One Class, the One class calls metodo of Two Class ..... till Class Five , what i wana achive is , if any Exception Occurs in any method,I  have to save StackTrace in DataBase.To achive this i have written the following Code,it is working  fine . Could any one please suggest me is this correct way or is there any better approach ? Please suggest me. any suggestions will be  appreciate.
**Note : for testing purpose we have written in main() method**

```
public class MyTestException extends Exception {

private String stackTraceMessage;
private String excepMsg;
private String errorType;
private String errorMsg;
private Byte status;
public boolean msgSet ;

public MyTestException(String stackTraceMessage, String excepMsg, String errorType, String errorMsg, Byte status, boolean msgSet) {
    this.stackTraceMessage = stackTraceMessage;
    this.excepMsg = excepMsg;
    this.errorType = errorType;
    this.errorMsg = errorMsg;
    this.status = status;
    this.msgSet = msgSet;
}



public String getStackTraceMessage() {
    return stackTraceMessage;
}

public void setStackTraceMessage(String stackTraceMessage) {
    this.stackTraceMessage = stackTraceMessage;
}

public String getExcepMsg() {
    return excepMsg;
}

public void setExcepMsg(String excepMsg) {
    this.excepMsg = excepMsg;
}

public String getErrorType() {
    return errorType;
}

public void setErrorType(String errorType) {
    this.errorType = errorType;
}

public String getErrorMsg() {
    return errorMsg;
}

public void setErrorMsg(String errorMsg) {
    this.errorMsg = errorMsg;
}

public Byte getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(Byte status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public boolean isMsgSet() {
    return msgSet;
}

public void setMsgSet(boolean msgSet) {
    this.msgSet = msgSet;
}

}
```

One Class

```
public class One {
public static String getMsgFromOne() throws Exception {
    String msg = null;
    try {
        msg = Two.getMsgFromTwo();
    } catch (Exception e) {
       if(e instanceof MyTestException){
        MyTestException ex = (MyTestException) e;
           if (ex.isMsgSet()) {
            throw e;
        } else {
            throw new MyTestException(TestExp.getStackTraceMessage(e), e.getLocalizedMessage(), "ErrorType", "ErrMsg", new Byte("1"),true);
        }
       }else{
                throw new MyTestException(TestExp.getStackTraceMessage(e), e.getLocalizedMessage(), "ErrorType", "ErrMsg", new Byte("1"),true);
       }
    }
    return msg;
}
}
```

Two Class

```
public class Two {
 public static String getMsgFromTwo()throws Exception{
String msg = null;
    try {
        msg = Three.getMsgFromThree();
//            int a = 9 / 0;
    } catch (Exception e) {
       if(e instanceof MyTestException){
        MyTestException ex = (MyTestException) e;
           if (ex.isMsgSet()) {
            throw e;
        } else {
            throw new MyTestException(TestExp.getStackTraceMessage(e), e.getLocalizedMessage(), "ErrorType", "ErrMsg", new Byte("1"),true);
        }
       }else{
                throw new MyTestException(TestExp.getStackTraceMessage(e), e.getLocalizedMessage(), "ErrorType", "ErrMsg", new Byte("1"),true);
       }
    }
return  msg;
}
}
```

Three Class

```
public class Three {
 public static String getMsgFromThree()throws Exception{
String msg = null;
    try {
        msg = Four.getMsgFromTwo();
    } catch (Exception e) {
       if(e instanceof MyTestException){
        MyTestException ex = (MyTestException) e;
           if (ex.isMsgSet()) {
            throw e;
        } else {
            throw new MyTestException(TestExp.getStackTraceMessage(e), e.getLocalizedMessage(), "ErrorType", "ErrMsg", new Byte("1"),true);
        }
       }else{
                throw new MyTestException(TestExp.getStackTraceMessage(e), e.getLocalizedMessage(), "ErrorType", "ErrMsg", new Byte("1"),true);
       }

    }
return  msg;
}
}
```

Four Class

```
public class Four {
  public static String getMsgFromTwo() throws Exception{
String msg = null;
    try {
        msg = Five.getMsgFromFive();
//           int a=0;
//     a= 8/0;
//           if(a==0)
//            throw new RemoteException("~~~~~~~~~ Rm Exp");
    } catch (Exception e) {
       if(e instanceof MyTestException){
        MyTestException ex = (MyTestException) e;
           if (ex.isMsgSet()) {
            throw e;
        } else {
            throw new MyTestException(TestExp.getStackTraceMessage(e), e.getLocalizedMessage(), "ErrorType", "ErrMsg", new Byte("1"),true);
        }
       }else{
                throw new MyTestException(TestExp.getStackTraceMessage(e), e.getLocalizedMessage(), "ErrorType", "ErrMsg", new Byte("1"),true);
       }
    }
return  msg;
}
}
```

Five Class

```
public class Five {

public static String getMsgFromFive() throws Exception {
    String msg = null;
    try {
//            msg = "Hello from 5";
        int a = 9 / 0;
//            if (a == 0) {
//                throw new MyTestException("StackTrace Five", "ExcMessage", "ErrorType", "ErrMsg", new Byte("1"),false);
//            }
    } catch (Exception e) {
       if(e instanceof MyTestException){
        MyTestException ex = (MyTestException) e;
           if (ex.isMsgSet()) {
            throw e;
        } else {
            throw new MyTestException(TestExp.getStackTraceMessage(e), e.getLocalizedMessage(), "ErrorType", "ErrMsg", new Byte("1"),true);
        }
       }else{
                throw new MyTestException(TestExp.getStackTraceMessage(e), e.getLocalizedMessage(), "ErrorType", "ErrMsg", new Byte("1"),true);
       }
    }
    return msg;
}


}
```

Main Program (this would be servelet)

```
public class TestExp {

/**
 * 
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        One.getMsgFromOne();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Saving all these Values in Database Table
        MyTestException e = (MyTestException) ex;
        System.out.println("1."+e.getErrorMsg());
        System.out.println("2."+e.getErrorType());
        System.out.println("3."+e.getStackTraceMessage());
        System.out.println("4."+e.getStatus());
        System.out.println("5."+e.getExcepMsg());

    }
}

public static String getStackTraceMessage(Exception e)  {

    StackTraceElement[] stackTraceArray = e.getStackTrace();
    String strStackTrace = "" + e;
    for (StackTraceElement stackTraceElement : stackTraceArray) {
        strStackTrace += " \n Class Name :- " + stackTraceElement.getClassName() + ", Method Name :- " + stackTraceElement.getMethodName() + " , Line Number :- " + stackTraceElement.getLineNumber();

    }
    return strStackTrace;

}
}
```

I have commented some lines to Testing purpose
Please suggest me. any suggestions will be  appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion, you might want to also add the cause to your message, for example...

```
public static String getStackTraceMessage(Exception e)  {

    String strStackTrace = "";

    while(e != null) {
        StackTraceElement[] stackTraceArray = e.getStackTrace();
        strStackTrace = "" + e;
        for (StackTraceElement stackTraceElement : stackTraceArray) {
            strStackTrace += " \n Class Name :- " + stackTraceElement.getClassName() + ", Method Name :- " + stackTraceElement.getMethodName() + " , Line Number :- " + stackTraceElement.getLineNumber();

        }

        if(e == e.getCause()) {
            e = null;
        } else {
           e = e.getCause();
           strStackTrace += "\nCaused by ";
        }
   } 
   return strStackTrace;
}
```

(I have not run this so it might not work, but you get the idea)

Make sure you have enough space in that text column!!

Comment: Another thing, why bother with your "MyTestException"? Just catch all in the servlet?

Comment: could you plz elobrate "why bother with your "MyTestException"? Just catch all in the servlet? "

Comment: @LMK In your "One...Five" classes, don't bother with try...catch at all. Just let any exception be thrown up to the try...catch block in you "main" and then you can create your "MyTestException" type stuff in there